# Ubuntu Quickly: How do I set a button to launch a specific Ubuntu Application

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, button

I'm very new to linux and I don't know very much. I was creating my own application with Quickly, and I wanted to have a button which launches the Hardware Information application "Hardinfo". I'm very new and I literally don't know anything, any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Update: I'm not looking for a keyboard shortcut, by button I meant a gtk-button inside glade. How to I set it so that when clicked it would take me to the application "hardinfo". If this isn't possible, then how can I set the button to emulate a keyboard shortcut once clicked, inside glade, Thankssssss!

Update 2: What I'm looking for is a step by step process of how to do this from someone who knows glade and quickly completely, because I have no idea how the codes work and where I'm supposed to put them :/

Comment: if you are looking for keyboard shortcut to launch a program  [see this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83962/assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, how about a clear and concise (working) example:

1. `quickly create ubuntu-application test`
2. `cd test`
3. `quickly design`
4. Add a button somewhere with Glade (by default it is called "button1")
5. Save and close Glade
6. `quickly edit` and go to TestWindow.py
7. Add the following at the top of the file:

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Process
   import subprocess
   ```
8. Add the following to the end of the file and make sure it is indented properly (pro tip: select the block of text in Gedit and hit tab to indent the whole block):

   ```
   def on_button1_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
       p = Process(target=self.launch_hardinfo)
       p.start()

   def launch_hardinfo(self):
       subprocess.call(["hardinfo"])
   ```

   These two functions work together. Process.start() calls TestWindow.launch_hardinfo (that's the target= parameter to the Process constructor) in a new thread so that subprocess.call() doesn't block the application.
9. Save TestWindow.py
10. `quickly run` and and click the button.

I had a little issue because I was trying to assign signals in Glade, but you don't even need to do that. The Quickly library actually allows you to do stuff like on_button1_click() which means "when the control called button1 is clicked." Simple as that! Hopefully this should get you started.

See also: [Creating Ubuntu Application with Quickly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GL153EWDTjQ)

Comment: I still don't know how to go about doing this :/

Answer (score 0):

Had to boot up Ubuntu in a VM for this one, I don't use Unity ;)

You can set up custom keybinds by opening the launcher (top left-hand button) and going to "Keyboard." From there you can go to the "Shortcuts" tab and create a custom shortcut. Name it whatever you wish, but make the command "hardinfo" (no quotes). After that's completed, click the right-hand side of the line that was just added to set your keystroke.

Comment: Nooo I'm not looking for a keyboard shortcut, by button I meant a gtk-button inside glade. How do I set it so that when clicked it would take me to the application "hardinfo". Thank you!!!

Comment: Oh, wow >.<. I must have totally missed the "creating my own application" part. Let me see if I can find your answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Quickly. What language does it use? C? Python?

Comment: Quickly uses Python

Comment: OK, give me a minute and I'll have your answer up.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this. I can't do this in Python, only in Perl, but it will look similar in Python.

```
sub startapp {
    system "/usr/bin/name_of_application &";
}

$button = Gtk2::Button->new("Start application");
$button->signal_connect(clicked => \&startapp, $window);
$button->show;
```

Comment: What should I do with that? haha sorry I dont know anything about coding :')

Comment: Is it not preferred to use the os.system() call as noted [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.system). That was also going to by my re-done answer to the question, but after seeing the info on the Python documentation, I changed it.

Comment: @Githlar I know, or rather, what you say rings a bell. However, the system call, with its limitations and probably security issues, has served me pretty well over the years. I wouldn't try this in a professional environment though.

Comment: I hear you. It's a standard call. The same could be said about Python threading ;) But in a system where the the program is usually in a waiting state such as this one, no harm done.